# Install h5py without sudo

Tags: python-2.7, pip, h5py

I'm trying to install `h5py` package via `pip` for python 2.7, I can't use `sudo` and I have python 3.2 installed too.

Here is my attemp:

I have installed pip:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py --user
```

then I installed `wheel`

`~/.local/bin/pip2.7 install --user wheel`

```
Collecting wheel
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0
```

Then installed `h5py`, seems it failed.

`~/.local/bin/pip2.7 install --user h5py`

```
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-2.5.0.tar.gz
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module pip was already imported from /home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.pyc, but /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from h5py)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Cython>=0.17 in /home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from h5py)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from h5py)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for h5py ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7KTR1Y/h5py/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpE1KVSupip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for h5py
  Running setup.py clean for h5py
Failed to build h5py
Installing collected packages: h5py
  Running setup.py install for h5py ... done
Successfully installed h5py-2.5.0
```

run python via `python2.7`

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import _conv
  File "h5py/h5r.pxd", line 21, in init h5py._conv (/tmp/pip-build-7KTR1Y/h5py/h5py/_conv.c:7356)
  File "h5py/_objects.pxd", line 12, in init h5py.h5r (/tmp/pip-build-7KTR1Y/h5py/h5py/h5r.c:2941)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 1, in init h5py._objects (/tmp/pip-build-7KTR1Y/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:7226)
ImportError: /home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/defs.so: undefined symbol: H5Oexists_by_name
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**

`~/.local/bin/pip2.7 show h5py`

```
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: h5py
Version: 2.5.0
Summary: Read and write HDF5 files from Python
Home-page: http://www.h5py.org
Author: Andrew Collette
Author-email: andrew dot collette at gmail dot com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, Cython, six
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Which OS? Which version of HDF5 do you have installed?

Comment: @aragilar see update.

Comment: That's h5py, not HDF5. The import exception is complaining about connecting between h5py and HDF5, which could be due to some version issue. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdf5/+bug/1418220, which could actually be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things happening here:

1. Missing SSL certificate problems (see the `urllib3` link)
2. `setuptools` not finding `wheel`, meaning a wheel isn't built, so `pip` calls `python setup.py install` directly
3. `h5py` is trying to use a function in HDF5 which does not exist in the version of HDF5 that's on your system.

1 and 2 are worth fixing (as they may be symptoms of other problems with the system), but 3 is the reason `h5py` isn't working for you.

`h5py` is trying to access `H5Oexists_by_name`. According to https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5O.html#Object-ExistsByName, this first appeared in version 1.8.5 of HDF5. According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/hdf5, the version of HDF5 on your system is 1.8.4 (but you need to check this!). Somehow `h5py` thinks the HDF5 library on you system is 1.8.5 or higher (see https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/4ee8f89b6dc658fdea5dc62d0f29058121928cfe/h5py/h5o.pyx#L172)

It looks like someone else has run into a similar problem, and filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdf5/+bug/1418220. You probably want to inform them of your problem, so that they can produce a bug fix.